# Copy specific columns from one sheet to another using vba macro code

Tags: vba, excel

I have to copy data from column U, AR and BF from sheet 1 and paste it to column A, B, C in sheet 2. I need a vba macro code for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `U, AR` and `BF` are the column name or index?

Comment: Index. @AbhinavRawat

Comment: This isn't code-writing service, you realize that? What is your specific question?

Comment: I have a code which is not working. That's why I'am asking here

Comment: The question is clear. I have to copy data from column U, AR and BF from sheet 1 and paste it to column A, B and C in sheet 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at

[How can I copy columns from one sheet to another with VBA in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990620/how-can-i-copy-columns-from-one-sheet-to-another-with-vba-in-excel)

[How to record macro in excel](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html)

```
 Sub foo1()

    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim trg As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long


    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set trg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")




    src.Range("U:U").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("A1")


    src.Range("AR:AR").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("B1")


    src.Range("BF:BF").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("C1")


    End Sub
```

Comment: If you declare `Dim LastRow, i As Long` then only `i` is of type `Long` but `LastRow` will be `Variant` it is exactly the same like `Dim LastRow As Variant, i As Long`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable like `Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long` otherwise Excel always assumes `Variant`!

Comment: @Peh oh! I didn't knew that, thanks for sharing, i'll keep that in my mind :)

Comment: sorry to say @AbhinavRawat this is giving me a huge error. When I run the macro it is shifting only the third column.

Comment: other 2 columns are being replaced by the third

Comment: @RavindraSinghRawat try now